# Spring HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am trying to make an endpoint for downloading a video file. here is the code :

```
@GetMapping(value = "/video")
    public ResponseEntity getVideo() throws MalformedURLException {
        FileSystemResource fileSystemResource = new FileSystemResource("E:\\video\\hello.mp4");
        ResourceRegion region = new ResourceRegion(fileSystemResource,
                                                   0,
                                                   fileSystemResource.getFile().length());
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.PARTIAL_CONTENT)
                .contentType(MediaType.valueOf("video/mp4"))
                .contentLength(fileSystemResource.getFile().length())
                .body(region);
    }
```

i get this respone when trying to call the url :

```
org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation
```

**thank u in advance for your help**

Comment: Did you try to specify `produces= MediaType.valueOf("video/mp4")` in the `@Getmapping` annotation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) without ResourceRegion

```
    @GetMapping(value = "/video")
    public ResponseEntity getVideo() throws MalformedURLException {
        FileSystemResource fileSystemResource = new FileSystemResource("E:\\video\\hello.mp4");
//        ResourceRegion region = new ResourceRegion(fileSystemResource, 0, fileSystemResource.getFile().length());
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.PARTIAL_CONTENT)
                .contentType(MediaType.valueOf("video/mp4"))
                .contentLength(fileSystemResource.getFile().length())
                .body(fileSystemResource);
    }
```

2) or add converters to spring:

```
@Configuration
public class ApplicationConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {

    @Bean
    public ResourceRegionHttpMessageConverter regionMessageConverter() {
       return new ResourceRegionHttpMessageConverter();
    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        converters.add(regionMessageConverter());
        super.configureMessageConverters(converters);
    }
}
```

with fix controller:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/video")
public ResponseEntity<ResourceRegion> getVideo() {
    FileSystemResource fileSystemResource = new FileSystemResource("E:\\video\\hello.mp4");
    ResourceRegion region = new ResourceRegion(fileSystemResource, 0, fileSystemResource.getFile().length());
    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.PARTIAL_CONTENT)
            .contentType(MediaType.valueOf("video/mp4"))
            .contentLength(fileSystemResource.getFile().length())
            .body(region);
}
```

Comment: Your first solution worked I had to just change the status code from partial_content to ok. thanks again.